# How to set frontend compilation via the database

Tags: admin, database, sql, less, compilation

How do you set the front-end workflow option via the DB rather than the admin?

This is the setting I'm referring to:

```
Stores > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer > Front-end development workflow
```

Example use case is when I need to change something whilst DI compile is running for twenty million years.

Comment: search for path dev/front_end_development_workflow/type in core_config_data

Answer (score 2):

I've just found it (although @arushi beat me to it :P) it can be changed by altering the path `dev/front_end_development_workflow/type` within `core_config_data` and setting the value to `client_side_compilation`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. log into mysql
2. select database
3. Run below command:

update core_config_data set value='server_side_compilation'  where path = 'dev/front_end_development_workflow/type';